# click a element with data-video-id on page load with javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello I have a **wordpress page** that im trying to make it so that when someone hits my page with the **#click_approved** parameter on the url- it triggers a link with data-video attribute to open a modal. So far i drafted this JS but no luck

```js
<script>
if(document.URL.indexOf("#click_approved") >= 0) { 
  document.querySelector('[data-video-id="5MS_V0SpRL8"]').click();
}
</script>
```

also tried this

```js
<script> 
var element = document.querySelector("a[data-video-id='5MS_V0SpRL8']");
if(document.URL.indexOf('#click_approved') >= 0) { 
  setTimeout(function(){element.click();}, 5000); 
} 
</script>
```

this is the page I'm trying to get the function to work on

https://www.homecarepulse.com/home-care-tv/recruitment-retention/#click_approved

any help is appreciated!

Comment: you cant trigger a click if the user has not clicked, instead just set the CSS to show it or call the event handlers function directly vs trying to trigger an event handler

Comment: Can I show you the page to see how I would do that? I’m not familiar with how to set it up. I thought I could simulate a click on a page

Comment: I tried this set up... no luck
``` 
<script>
var element = document.querySelector("a[data-video-id='5MS_V0SpRL8']");


if(document.URL.indexOf('#click_approved') >= 0){  
  setTimeout(function(){element.click();}, 5000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i have triggered clicks on elements with javascript before...not sure why this would be different

Comment: I looked for `data-video-id='5MS_V0SpRL8'` its not on the dom so must be loaded by ajax etc, you don't seem to be wrapping your code in an onload event.. look at browser console for errors your see its not found

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah it gets loaded thorough a plugin, im not sure how to write out what your suggesting, can you show me a example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just move `querySelector` into the `setTimeout` callback function.

```js
<script> 
if(document.URL.indexOf('#click_approved') >= 0) { 
  setTimeout(function(){
      var element = document.querySelector("a[data-video-id='5MS_V0SpRL8']");
      element.click();
  }, 5000); 
} 
</script>
```

or reduce wait time using a `setInterval`

```js
<script>
(function() {
    if (document.URL.indexOf('#click_approved') === -1) return;
    let tm = setInterval(function(){
        var a = document.querySelector("a[data-video-id='5MS_V0SpRL8']");
        if (a) {
            clearInterval(tm);
            a.click();
        }
    }, 500);
})();
</script>
```

and here is another way using [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), it's more efficient than the timer way. it ensures that click event can be triggered immediately once the element is rendered.

```js
<script>
(function() {
    if (document.URL.indexOf('#click_approved') === -1) return;

    let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (!mutation.addedNodes) return
        for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (node.tagName == 'A' && node.getAttribute('data-video-id') == '5MS_V0SpRL8') {
                node.click();
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true
      , subtree: true
      , attributes: false
      , characterData: false
    });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: i used your 2nd option! thank you so much @emptyhua